# Track string match in url for react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I want to trigger a function whenever the url contains a specific keyword.
Any idea on how this can be done?

NOTE : It can be done separately for each route, but that would be a tedious solution.

Comment: You can track the url in the parent state and pass it to a child prop which could be a HOC. The handle logic would be in that single child of the parent.

Answer (score 2):

1. You basically want to listen for @@router/LOCATION_CHANGE action type to be dispatched, or whichever the action type is for your version of react-router.
2. Then use a regex or some kind of matcher.

   ```
   const url = www.google.com/routeParam
   const newRegex = new RegExp(/routeParam/, "gi");
   const hasKeyWord = url.match(newRegex);
   if (hasKeyWord) {
       console.log("// ... we can do function here")
   }
   ```